# Insert a checkbox selection value into database as Bit field using PHP

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I've been through a few similar questions for this, however, with my basic knowledge I haven't been able to find an answer that I can tie directly to what I'm trying to achieve.

For instance, I have found answers regarding arrays to store multiple checkbox values. However, I'm not sure if this is what I need as each of the 3 checkboxes i have are for individual columns in the database.

This is my HTML that i have currently for checkboxes etc:

```
<form action="addNewClient.php" method="POST">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Please enter the name of the client you wish to create.</p>
            <textarea id="addSQLNoteName" placeholder="Enter client name..." name="title" maxlength="25"></textarea>
            <p>Teams Packge:</p>
            <select name="package">
              <option value="SBE">SBE</option>
              <option value="Enterprise">Enterprise</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="portal" value="1"> Premium Portal
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="replicated" value="1"> Replicated
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="client" value="1"> IT Client
            <br />
            <textarea id="addSQLNoteName" placeholder="Important client info..." name="info" maxlength="25"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer footer-sqlnotes">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Client</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

This is my current PHP code and ive made a few comments just showing which ones are the checkboxes:

```
<?php include 'connectionDetails.php'; ?>

<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['package'], $_POST['portal'], $_POST['replicated'], $_POST['client'], $_POST['info']))
{
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $package = $_POST['package']; 
    $portal = $_POST['portal'];         //Checkbox
    $replicated = $_POST['replicated']; //Checkbox
    $client = $_POST['client'];         //Checkbox
    $info = $_POST['info'];

    $stmt = "INSERT INTO Clients (Client, TeamsPackage, Rating, Pos, Neg, PremiumPortal, Replicated, ITClient, ClientInfo) VALUES (?, ?, 0, 0, 0, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $params = array($title, $package, $portal, $replicated, $client, $info);

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $stmt, $params);

    if ($stmt === false) 
    {
        die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    header('location: clients.php');
}

else
{
    echo "No Data";

}


?>
```

And so in my database, I have three bit field columns, if checked when submitted it will enter as a 1 otherwise it will enter as a 0.

Like I said, I apologise if another question does answer mine, I just couldn't seem to implement it over to what i am trying to achieve.

***At the moment, if all 3 boxes are checked then it will add the client, otherwise it fails the isset() which is what I'm trying to get around at the moment.***

Comment: do the session arrays contain value? I don't see where they've been set and assigned to something.

Comment: I think you should have used POST and not SESSION for the arrays in the `isset()` and it doesn't get through that conditional. It's hard to say what you want to use/do here though.

Comment: Apologies, those shouldn't be sessions i'll alter those now, pretend you didn't see that bit

Comment: I would use a ternary operator for all this instead and just use an `isset()` on a submit button, then the ternaries inside that. Use error reporting and check for errors on the query.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i'll have to look at some examples of using a ternary operator as i haven't come across that before. Thanks for the response as well.

Comment: There's an example on php.net http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php - just replace the `empty` with `isset` and change the POST arrays' names for the ones you want. You can do this, I'm sure ;-) `isset()` is for checkboxes/radios and `empty()` for text inputs, as a side note.

Comment: Why dont you just assign a default value when the check boxes come empty

Comment: ^ a ternary operator does that. Using multiple isset()'s is just cumbersome. Ternaries are much cleaner.

Comment: @LukeLitherland I posted something for you to have a look at below.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of this entire statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['package'], $_POST['portal'], $_POST['replicated'], $_POST['client'], $_POST['info']))
```

Name your submit button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">Add Client</button>
```

Then change your conditional to:

*Side note: See the **Edit:** below.*

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $portal = (isset($_POST['portal'])) ? '0' : $_POST['portal'];
    $replicated = (isset($_POST['replicated'])) ? '0' : $_POST['replicated'];
    $client = (isset($_POST['client'])) ? '0' : $_POST['client'];

    // add your other form elements 

    // Perform your query here
}
```

Ternary operators are IMHO, what should be used here.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Using a default value of `0`.

You can add the other conditionals from your original post for the other form elements.

---

**Edit:**

I made a mistake with the `isset()`'s for the ternaries. Those should have read as `!isset()` checking if they are "not" set.

So, I rewrote it as the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

     $portal = !isset($_POST['portal']) ? '0' : $_POST['portal'];
     $replicated = !isset($_POST['replicated']) ? '0' : $_POST['replicated'];
     $client = !isset($_POST['client']) ? '0' : $_POST['client'];

    // add your other form elements 

    // Perform your query here
}
```

Comment: that is what i meant to do. it is much cleaner and error safe

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz which is what I told the OP also. I guess they were probably on the php.net website and trying to do it themselves, or they needed a slight nudge ;-) Cheers

Comment: One observation. checkboxes return `on` when checked, so instead `$_POST['var_name'];` should go `1`

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz they return `on` when checked only if there is no "preset value" ;-) which they have now. The ternary default of `0` takes care of that.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner what am i setting the default values to in the HTML for the check boxes?

Comment: @LukeLitherland don't worry about that. The way that ternaries work is that if they are not set/checked, then they default to `0`, otherwise they are 1's. Give it a go and see ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner oh ok, so if it makes those in the html redundant then i can take those out?

Comment: @LukeLitherland you can keep what you have now for the HTML checkboxes, you need them.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner ok so i checked the box for 'Replicated' and not the other 2 as a test and the one i ticked entered the one i checked as 0 in the database and the ones i didnt are null, is there anyway to make the one i checked a 1 in the database and the others that are NULL a 0?

Comment: @LukeLitherland this tells me that your column types are not `int` or you've given the columns a default value of NULL and to accept NULL values. You can either ALTER your columns to be `int`'s if they're not that already and give them a default value of `0` instead. I find it rather odd that you're getting NULL's instead of `0`'s here. Also to make them NOT NULL.

Comment: @LukeLitherland not to tie up comments too much here since it triggered to automatically move comments to chat; you can give your checkbox columns a default value of `0` rather than NULL which seems to be the case and to ALTER them to be NOT NULL instead. That way, it will accept the `0` for the ternary defaults, and will also ensure that `0` is used in the table if none are selected.

Comment: Ok so i have made it so they do not accept NULL, set the default values to 0 and changed the columns from bit to int just to be safe. However i now get this error:  Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PremiumPortal', table 'DiscoverThePlanet.dbo.Clients'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: @LukeLitherland *Hm....*, well I am baffled. Do the (`int`) columns have a length for them? What we've talked about and done should have worked.

Comment: The ints have no limits on them, how do you move a comment section to a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162524/discussion-between-funk-forty-niner-and-luke-litherland).

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @FunkFortyNiner who left me with this solution in a discussion.

```
if(isset($_POST['portal'])){ 

$portal = $_POST['portal']; 

}else{ 

$portal = 0; 

}
```

His original answer for some reason wasn't entering the correct values, however this that he suggested has worked.

Rather than using a ternary operator, just doing an isset statement on each of the check boxes and if not checked setting it to 0.

Comment: I find it really odd that the ternaries didn't work. Oh well, if it works now ;-)

Comment: It is strange, but like you said at least its working.

Comment: did you in fact try removing the quotes around the zeros, going from `$portal = (isset($_POST['portal'])) ? '0' : $_POST['portal'];` to `$portal = (isset($_POST['portal'])) ? 0 : $_POST['portal'];` and doing the same for the others?

Comment: I remember doing that and it didn't fix it :(

Comment: Gosh darn it Luke, I now see where I made a mistake in my ternaries. Those should have read as `!isset()` checking if they are "not" set. I've made an edit to my answer, under **Edit:**. Sorry about that; that was an oversight on my part.

Comment: No problem, it completely slipped me too! Im glad you found it though :)

Comment: Yeah, my brain didn't compute the `empty()` and `isset()` are two different animals altogether. `empty()` and `!isset()` however, are rather closely related (animals) *lol!* Oh well, *c'est la vie*. I'll remember that one.